# Python 3.5 insert record into Postgres table on another schema

Tags: sqlalchemy, schema, insert-into, python-3.5

.....my postgres db class ......

```
class User(db.Model):
    """docstring for User"""

    __tablename__ = 'user'
    user_name = db.Column(db.String(45), primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(45))

    def __init__(self, user_name, email):
        super(User, self).__init__()
        self.user_name = user_name
        self.email = email
```

.....when an insert is attempted I get error message

```
@app.route('/add_user', methods=['POST'])
def add_user():
    user = User(user_name = request.form['user_name'], email = request.form['email'])
    print(user.user_name, user.email)
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template('get_address.html')

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) relation "user" does not exist LINE 1: INSERT INTO "user" (user_name, email) VALUES ('as', 'sd') ^ [SQL: 'INSERT INTO "user" (user_name, email) VALUES (%(user_name)s, %(email)s)'] [parameters: {'email': 'sd', 'user_name': 'as'}]
```

.....there are multiple schemas that are being used
.....the above class is in a schema called users

I think the issue is the table name resolution: i.e in the database where is the table 'users'? I assumed one must qualify the table 'users' with the schema name of `__tablename__ = 'users.user'`. This does not work.

...the error produced is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) relation "users.user" does not exist LINE 1: INSERT INTO "users.user" (user_name, email) VALUES ('po', 'p... ^ [SQL: 'INSERT INTO "users.user" (user_name, email) VALUES (%(user_name)s, %(email)s)'] [parameters: {'email': 'po', 'user_name': 'po'}]
```

I cannot find on [SqlAlchemy.org](http://sqlalchemy.org) site or anywhere else any info on any construct to be used or how to address this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the schema name with the [`schema` argument to `Table`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#specifying-the-schema-name):

```
class User(db.Model):
    ...
    __table_args__ = {
        "schema": "users"
    }
```